# Whats the alternative syntax for ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

With the introduction of ActiveModel in Rails 3 whats the new method of calling ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. ActiveModel::RecordNotFound ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition ([1](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/ActiveModel.html)) of ActiveModel:

> ActiveModel is a class to be implemented by each ORM to allow Rails to generate customized controller code.

ActiveRecord implements ActiveModel. ActiveRecord raises its ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception when it can't find record by given id or a set of ids ([2](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotFound.html)) in the database.

This mean there can't be such exception like ActiveModel::RecordNotFound.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveModel is a set of modules and conventions to be implemented, the main goal being providing a common interface to mappers, no more, no less. So nope, `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` stays `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. `RecordNotFound` does not make sense for every mapper : with Mongoid for instance, you'll have `DocumentNotFound` (well, `Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound`).